# Kcheckpass errors?

Tags: fedora, kde

Running Fedora 33 with Plasma. I've noticed these repeating errors in journalctl for yesterday.

```
Mar 11 16:11:43 lap.localdomain kcheckpass[159270]: pam_unix(kde:auth): auth could not identify password for [name]
Mar 11 16:11:43 lap.localdomain kcheckpass[159270]: pam_unix(kde:auth): conversation failed
```

If i lock the laptop now though, then unlock, these errors are not repeated today.

Any ideas please on what they maybe caused by?

Thanks